# flatten and separate objects on elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I wonder if there is a magic method on elasticsearch that save this kind of data :

**Input**

```
{
    id : 1,
    name : "name1",
    articles : [{
        title : "title1",
        description : "description1"
    },{
        title : "title2",
        description : "description2"
    }
    ] 
}
```

into this :

**Data saved on Elasticsearch**

```
[
    {
        id:1,
        name:"name1",
        articles: {
            title:"title1",
            description:"description1"
        }
    },
    {
        id:1,
        name:"name1",
        articles: {
            title:"title2",
            description:"description2"
        }
    }
]
```

I already found the [Nested Type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) on elasticsearch website, but it doesn't match.

Any idea ? Thanks

Comment: Convert it with JQ (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) and then post to ES ?